# Install apps via Portainer on a Raspberry Pi and expose over internet

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, reverse-proxy, self-hosting, portainer

Following [this](https://www.wundertech.net/portainer-raspberry-pi-install-how-to-install-docker-and-portainer/) then [this](https://www.wundertech.net/nginx-proxy-manager-raspberry-pi-install-instructions/comment-page-4/), I have Portainer, Docker and NGINX reverse proxy set up on a Raspberry Pi connected to my home router. I have an SSD mounted at `/media/ssd`. I'm ready to start installing services and accessing them from outside my home. I'd like to start with Nextcloud, if possible. I'm wondering what are the steps?

I tried myself using [this](https://www.diytechguru.com/2020/12/29/install-nextcloud-on-docker/) tutorial but got the following error:

```
failed to deploy a stack: service "mariadb" refers to undefined network bridge: invalid compose project
```

I'm new to Portainer / Docker, any guidance appreciated.